# How can I let the list page remember some params?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue project, but there is a issue to me,

[image]

In my `router.js`:

```
{
      path: '/home/aftersale_physicalserver_workpanel/:use_flag/:areapartition_homeshowtext',
      meta: { keepAlive: true },
      icon: 'compose',
      name: 'aftersale_physicalserver_workpanel',
      title: 'work panel',
      component: resolve => {
        require(['./views/main_home/home/components/general_admin_staff_panel/physicalserver/physicalserver_workpanel.vue'], resolve);
      }
    },
```

there is the code:

```
...
<template>
  <lml-page
     ref="lml_page_ref"
     v-if=" origin_data && origin_data.count"
     :data_count="origin_data.count"
     :current.sync="cur_page"
     @change_page_for_parent="server_change_page">
  </lml-page>
</template>
...

<script>
  export default {
  props: {
    ...
    cur_page: 1,
  },
</script>
```

you see the cur_page is the page number. I want the URL append the page number.
because when I enter a detail page, when I go back, there will go to page 1 by default.

---

**My purpose**

my purpose is let the list_page remember some params. such as the upper page_number, and some search params. but in Vue I don't know how.

When I from a searched params page enter a detail page, when I go back:

```
<span class="go-left" @click="$router.go(-1)">
   <Icon type="chevron-left"></Icon>
   <span>Go back</span>
</span>
```

there will get a list_page without the searched data.

Comment: You should use Vuex. When you navigate away from your list, you commit the current position. When you get back to it, it's read from the store. Note there are simpler state management patterns than Vuex but, in the long run, learning how to use Vuex pays off.

Comment: It is not clear what `CD-Z` is in the URL: is it already the page? Or is it a category and the page is still missing?

Comment: why not something like `.../:use_flag/:areapartition_homeshowtext/:page_number`

Comment: @appleapple because there are also many other search params. not all have value.

Comment: @Sergeon it is `areapartition_homeshowtext `.

Comment: but `page_number` have

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use either local storage or a central state, what I use is vuex like this:

```
onPageChange: function (pageNo) {
        this.$store.dispatch(this.$mts.some.SOMETHING, pageNo);
      },
```

Then you can call your store wherever you need and `get` the page number.
Look for the vuex docs on how to setup state management.
Like this:

```
this.page = this.$store.getters.some.page
```

Comment: I understand your idea. but there is an issue there, I just want the go back(`$router.go(-1)` ) to the list page use the store search and store page data to filter data. if I enter the list by other method, I wouldn't.

Comment: Not sure I follow you but once you leave the route your data is gone, so going back is not going to do anything except re-render the previous page any data needs to be saved in some sort of central store.

Comment: I understand you. but my meaning is: when I from detail page enter the list page, your idea works fine, but if I from page A/B/C enter the list page, there will render it by the store data too, this is not my want.

Comment: In that case in your route set `props: true` then pass into the props through the route a boolean, then make the fetching of saved data from store dependant on the incoming prop.

Comment: can you explain more about the `In that case in your route set props: true then pass into the props through the route a boolean,`?

Comment: From the docs: 
```const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/user/:id', component: User, props: true },
    ...
})
//then when you change the route it would look something like this:
this.$router.push({name: 'EditQuery', params: { query_id: id }})
//Then in the 'EditQuery' component you would either receive the query_id as a //prop or get it off the params in the route.Like this:
this.query_id = this.$route.params.query_id;```